# Angular failed to load image

Tags: html, css, angular, performance, webp

I used images in my project, I changed the HTML structure and converted all the images in the assets folder. [Use WebP images](https://web.dev/articles/serve-images-webp)
And they all work well when the page loads.
BUT, when switching to another route, many errors appear in the console. how to fix this?
Another page uses a lot of the same images, as far as I understand, it says that it doesn’t load them, but how can I ensure that these messages don’t appear in the console..

[image]

```html
<picture>
    <source type="image/webp"
            srcset="./../../../../../assets/images/summerVersion/restaurant/DSC_0380.webp">
    <source type="image/jpeg"
            srcset="./../../../../../assets/images/summerVersion/restaurant/DSC_0380.jpg">
    <img class="img-fluid"
         src="./../../../../../assets/images/summerVersion/restaurant/DSC_0380.jpg"
         alt="Фото ресторану">
</picture>
```